# Embed widgets with jupyter-cadquery (threejs): wrong position on load

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, three.js, ipywidgets, cadquery

I am using [`jupyter-cadquery`](https://github.com/bernhard-42/jupyter-cadquery) to visualize some 3D models made with [CadQuery](https://github.com/CadQuery/cadquery).

When visualizing the models on a Jupyter notebook, everything works as expected.

But when trying to embed the widget in an HTML document, it seems the camera, on load, is pointing to `(0, 0, 0)`, not as expected. Once you interact with the widget, the camera will point to the expected coordinate.

Here is the code to reproduce the error and an animation of the mentioned problem (see instructions bellow on how to reproduce it with Binder):

```py
from cadquery import Workplane
from ipywidgets import embed
from jupyter_cadquery.cad_view import CadqueryView
from jupyter_cadquery.cadquery import Assembly
from jupyter_cadquery.cadquery import Part


# Create a simple assembly
box1 = Workplane('XY').box(10, 10, 10).translate((0, 0, 5))
a1 = Assembly([Part(box1)], "example 1")

# Generate HTML
a1.collect_shapes()
view = CadqueryView()
for shape in a1.collect_shapes():
    view.add_shape(shape["name"], shape["shape"], shape["color"])
renderer = view.render()
embed.embed_minimal_html('export.html', views=renderer, title='Renderer')

renderer
```

[image: output]

Note how the view of the cube "jumps" suddenly on interaction.

Could it be an issue with `ipywidgets`? Since the view is okay when displayed in the notebook.

How could it be fixed?

## How to reproduce

You can reproduce it with Binder, without needing to create a local environment (admitedly, installing CadQuery/jupyter-cadquery is not the easiest/fastest thing to do):

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/bernhard-42/jupyter-cadquery/master?urlpath=lab&filepath=examples%2Fcadquery.ipynb

Just execute the code above in a new empty notebook. See how the `renderer` shows the 3D model without any issues on the notebook:

[image: Screenshot from 2019-12-23 21-28-42]

After execution, an `export.html` document will also appear in the file list on the left. Open it and make sure to click on the "Trust HTML" button on top of the viewer and hit refresh. If you interact with the view, you can reproduce the issue.

[image: Screenshot from 2019-12-23 21-25-21]

Note that, also, the perspective is lost (that is not an orthogonal view). Fixing that would be a plus! ^^

Comment: mm....I think that there is some problem with the translate. Just try to put     box1 = Workplane('XY').box(10, 10, 10).translate((10, 10, 10)). Trsnalate == box, you will see that in html the box has the correct position. I know that it change the figure, but it is an start point.

Comment: @DiegoBaranowski Thanks for your comment. I know about that but, unfortunately, it is not a solution. The translation is part of the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yes..I tried with embed_data and put the html in a template (see here: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html#python-interface), but same error.

Comment: @ZF007 [CadQuery](https://github.com/CadQuery/cadquery) does not depend on FreeCAD. It used to, but that is no longer the case. I reverted your edit.

Comment: The cadquery 1.2.0 does not run without FreeCAD. It keeps throwing an import error. After proper directions where to find it threw a new error that is only runs on python 3.6 due to a specific dll. I'm trying to get that fixed in anaconda by installing a new environment. (got a lot of CAD progs but never ran in FreeCAD so its a nice Christmas exercise ;-)

Comment: Even cadquery 2.0 is a nightmare and didn't get it installed yet. opt-out for now unfortunately.

Comment: @ZF007 CadQuery 1.x is no longer maintained, just go for CadQuery 2.0. ;-) CadQuery 2.0 is easy to install if you have Conda. `jupyter-cadquery` is a bit harder, but you have a Dockerfile in the GitHub repository if you get along with Docker. Otherwise, you can try everything out with Binder, as noted in the question. Thanks for giving it a try anyways. ^^

Comment: ... it might take a few days to get it all properly installed. Did file githit bugreport on the 1.2 version and then later figured out beased on your comment about the 2.0. That threw another trceback error. File that one too. So its waiting how to fix it. Once Installed I can check it (also because I can use parts to automate some things for our website ;-)

Comment: Posted my answer at both of the questions; slightly different from each other at the start of the answer. My suggestion would be to merge both questions onto one. But hey..thats' me ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be reproduced without the need of `jupyter-cadquery`, so a new question has been opened instead:

[Embed widgets with pythreejs: wrong perspective and camera look-at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586889/embed-widgets-with-pythreejs-wrong-perspective-and-camera-look-at)

Answer (score 0):

It took a few days, didn't get cadquery working properly, but your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586889/embed-widgets-with-pythreejs-wrong-perspective-and-camera-look-at) on this topic without cadquery made it possible to look at the issue...

The jumping happens because `orbit.update()` for target does not occurs and the function `update()` is not available in python; only in c++ or c#, etc. From the docs:

> When animating the camera rotation above, we used the camera’s
>   quaternion
>   . This is the most robust method for
>   animating free-form rotations.  For example, the animation above was created by first moving the camera manually, and then reading out its position and quaternion properties at the wanted views...

The text can be found [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pythreejs/downloads/pdf/latest/) on page 12. And also discussed [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/pythreejs/issues/166) at github.

However, the jumping can be reproduced in IPython if you apply the following:

`renderer = Renderer(scene=scene, camera=camera, controls=[orbit], position=target, width=view_width, height=view_height)`

here `position` is added with target coordinates [0, 5, 0] but the update for this is only done when you mouse-click and adjust to position of the cube/camera. The jump is similar/equal to the jump as seen in the export.HTML.

Conclusion: the programmed camera position is seen as a jump after manual interference due to the absense of the `.update()` function of the OrbitControls python class and thus not a bug or mistake.